# Array.prototype.forEach() not working when called on a proxy with a get handler

Tags: javascript, foreach, ecmascript-6, iteration, es6-proxy

I have the following proxy:

```
const p = new Proxy({
  [Symbol.iterator]: Array.prototype.values,
  forEach: Array.prototype.forEach,
}, {
  get(target, property) {
    if (property === '0') return 'one';
    if (property === '1') return 'two';
    if (property === 'length') return 2;
    return Reflect.get(target, property);
  },
});
```

It's an array-like object, because it has numeric properties and the `length` property specifying the amount of elements. I can iterate it using a `for...of` loop:

```
for (const element of p) {
  console.log(element); // logs 'one' and 'two'
}
```

However, the `forEach()` method is not working.

```
p.forEach(element => console.log(element));
```

This code doesn't log anything. The callback function is never called. Why isn't it working and how can I fix it?

Code snippet:

```js
const p = new Proxy({
  [Symbol.iterator]: Array.prototype.values,
  forEach: Array.prototype.forEach,
}, {
  get(target, property) {
    if (property === '0') return 'one';
    if (property === '1') return 'two';
    if (property === 'length') return 2;
    return Reflect.get(target, property);
  },
});

console.log('for...of loop:');
for (const element of p) {
  console.log(element);
}

console.log('forEach():');
p.forEach(element => console.log(element));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-polyfill/6.16.0/polyfill.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You could just extend Array to not polyfill each and every feature that can become broken when being proxified.

Comment: @estus I could, but that doesn't fix it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One of the differences between a `for...of` loop and `Array.prototype.forEach()` is that the former uses the `@@iterator` property to loop over the object, while the latter iterates the properties from `0` to `length`, and executes the callback only if the object has that property. It uses a `[[HasProperty]]` internal method, which in this case returns `false` for every array element.

The solution is to add also the `has()` handler, which will intercept the `[[HasProperty]]` calls.

Working code:

```js
const p = new Proxy({
  [Symbol.iterator]: Array.prototype.values,
  forEach: Array.prototype.forEach,
}, {
  get(target, property) {
    if (property === '0') return 'one';
    if (property === '1') return 'two';
    if (property === 'length') return 2;
    return Reflect.get(target, property);
  },
  has(target, property) {
    if (['0', '1', 'length'].includes(property)) return true;
    return Reflect.has(target, property);
  },
});

p.forEach(element => console.log(element));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-polyfill/6.16.0/polyfill.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

There is an additional option that is relatively simple. Use `Array.from()` to generate an array that you can iterate over.

```
const a = Array.from(p);
a.forEach(element => console.log(element));
```

The full code:

```
const p = new Proxy({
  [Symbol.iterator]: Array.prototype.values,
  forEach: Array.prototype.forEach,
}, {
  get(target, property) {
    if (property === '0') return 'one';
    if (property === '1') return 'two';
    if (property === 'length') return 2;
    return Reflect.get(target, property);
  },
});

const a = Array.from(p);
a.forEach(element => console.log(element));
```

Answer (score 0):

if `targetObject` is of form `[{a:1, b:2}, {a: 3, b:4}, {a: 5, b: 6}]` to add `sudoKey` to each object we can below proxy

```
let proxy_array = new Proxy(targetObjectArray, {
        get: function (target, key) {
            if (!isNaN(parseInt(key))) {
                return { sudoKey: compute(), ...Reflect.get(target, key)}
            }
            return Reflect.get(target, key);
        }
    });
```

Example

```
let x = [{a: 1, b:2}, {a:3, b:4}, {a:5, b: 6}]

let y = new Proxy(x, {
        get: function (target, key) {
            if (!isNaN(parseInt(key))) {
                return { c: -1, ...Reflect.get(target, key)}
            }
            return Reflect.get(target, key);
        }
    });

y.forEach(e => console.log(e))
Output:
{c: -1, a: 1, b: 2}
{c: -1, a: 3, b: 4}
{c: -1, a: 5, b: 6}
```

here `!isNaN(parseInt(key))` is to to check whether `prop` is `ArrayIndex` (0, 1, 2 ... x.length - 1) or `Array.Prototype` keys which include forEach as a property

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) for Array.prototype which attach forEach the proxy Array